# Find maximum number of distinct square matrix in a mxn matrix

Tags: algorithm

There is a m x n matrix which contains either 0 or 1. A square submatrix of 2x2 is defined which contains only 0. If such square submatrix is cut from the original matrix then we have to find out the maximum number of such square sub matrices which can be cut from the original matrix. Cutting strictly means no 2 square sub matrix can overlap.
For ex -
This is a 5x5 matrix

```
0 0 0 1 0  
0 0 0 0 0  
1 0 0 0 0  
0 0 0 1 0  
0 0 0 0 0
```

If we cut a square submatrix of 2x2 starting from (0,0) then the remaining matrix is

```
    0 1 0  
    0 0 0  
1 0 0 0 0  
0 0 0 1 0  
0 0 0 0 0
```

Further 2x2 square sub matrices can be cut
In this give input maximum 3 such matrices can be cut. If I mark them with 'a'

```
a a 0 1 0  
a a a a 0  
1 0 a a 0  
a a 0 1 0  
a a 0 0 0
```

I have tried the backtracking/recursive approach but it can work only for lower size input. Can anybody suggest a more efficeint approach?

Edit: I have mark matrix elements with "a" to show that this is one sub matrix which can be cut. We have to report only maximum number of 2x2 submatrix (containing all 0) which can be taen from this matrix

Comment: Please post constraints for m and n.

Comment: I don't remember constraints exactly but I think m, n < 25

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness, I changed the script to do some crude recursion, you were right it's difficult to not resort to a recursive way of doing it...

The idea:

```
f(matrix,count)
    IF count > length THEN
        length = count
    add all options to L
    IF L is empty THEN
        return
    FOR each option in L
        FOR each position in option
            set position in matrix to 1
        f(matrix,count+1)
        FOR each position in option
            set position in matrix to 0 

where options are all 2x2 submatrices with only 0s that are currently in matrix 
length = 0
set M to the matrix with 1s and 0s
f(M,0)
```

In python:

```python
import copy 

def possibilities(y):
    l = len(y[0]) # horizontal length of matrix
    h = len(y) # verticle length of matrix
    sub = 2 # length of square submatrix you want to shift in this case 2x2
    length = l-sub+1
    hieght = h-sub+1
    x = [[0,0],[0,1],
         [1,0],[1,1]]
    # add all 2x2 to list L
    L=[]
    for i in range(hieght):
        for j in range(length):
            if y[x[0][0]][x[0][1]]==0 and y[x[1][0]][x[1][1]]==0 and y[x[2][0]][x[2][1]]==0 and y[x[3][0]][x[3][1]]==0:
                # create a copy of x
                c = copy.deepcopy(x)
                L.append(c)
            for k in x: # shift submatrix to the right 1
                k[1]+=1
        (x[0][1],x[1][1],x[2][1],x[3][1]) = (0,1,0,1)
        for k in x: # shift submatrix down 1
            k[0]+=1
    return L



def f(matrix,count):
    global length
    if count > length:
        length = count
    L = possibilities(matrix)
    if not L:
        return
    for option in L:
        for position in option:
            matrix[position[0]][position[1]]=1
        f(matrix,count+1)
        # reset back to 0
        for position in option:
            matrix[position[0]][position[1]]=0 

length = 0 
# matrix
M = [[0,0,1,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0,0],
     [1,1,0,0,0,0],
     [0,1,1,0,0,0]]
f(M,0)
print(length)
```

Comment: This approach will give incorrect answer for  0 0 1 0 0 0   ,0 0 0 0 0 0 , 1 1 0 0 0 0  , 0 1 1 0 0 0  . This code will return 3 while actual answer is 4.